# Basic Query, View questions

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to make this query

to create a view which will list top 10 products  most purchased in previous 6 months.

```
CREATE VIEW Top10product6month_VW AS
SELECT ProductID
FROM (select ProductID,SYSDATE - OrderDate AS OrderAge
      from DD_OrderLine
      WHERE SYSDATE - OrderDate <= 183)
Where ROWNUM <= 10;
```

and I could not get top10.

My OrderLine table is

```
CREATE TABLE DD_OrderLine
(
OrderDate DATE,
SUMofPrice NUMBER(8,2),
OrderID NUMBER(6),
ProductID NUMBER(6),
CONSTRAINT DD_orderid_productid_pk PRIMARY KEY (OrderID,ProductID )
);
```

and records are

```
INSERT INTO DD_OrderLine (OrderDate,SUMofPrice, QuantityPurchased,OrderID,ProductID)
VALUES ((to_date('2013/9/25', 'yyyy/mm/dd')),000010.00,1,000117,001116);
--
INSERT INTO DD_OrderLine (OrderDate,SUMofPrice, QuantityPurchased,OrderID,ProductID)
VALUES ((to_date('2013/9/14', 'yyyy/mm/dd')),000010.00,1,000118,001112);
--
INSERT INTO DD_OrderLine (OrderDate,SUMofPrice, QuantityPurchased,OrderID,ProductID)
VALUES ((to_date('2013/9/14', 'yyyy/mm/dd')),000010.00,1,000118,001111);
--
INSERT INTO DD_OrderLine (OrderDate,SUMofPrice, QuantityPurchased,OrderID,ProductID)
VALUES ((to_date('2013/9/15', 'yyyy/mm/dd')),000010.00,1,000119,001111);

INSERT INTO DD_OrderLine (OrderDate,SUMofPrice, QuantityPurchased,OrderID,ProductID)
VALUES ((to_date('2013/9/15', 'yyyy/mm/dd')),000010.00,1,000119,001112);

INSERT INTO DD_OrderLine (OrderDate,SUMofPrice, QuantityPurchased,OrderID,ProductID)
VALUES ((to_date('2013/9/24', 'yyyy/mm/dd')),000010.00,1,000120,001115);

INSERT INTO DD_OrderLine (OrderDate,SUMofPrice, QuantityPurchased,OrderID,ProductID)
VALUES ((to_date('2013/9/24', 'yyyy/mm/dd')),000010.00,1,000120,001114);

INSERT INTO DD_OrderLine (OrderDate,SUMofPrice, QuantityPurchased,OrderID,ProductID)
VALUES ((to_date('2013/9/24', 'yyyy/mm/dd')),000010.00,1,000120,001113);

INSERT INTO DD_OrderLine (OrderDate,SUMofPrice, QuantityPurchased,OrderID,ProductID)
VALUES ((to_date('2013/9/24', 'yyyy/mm/dd')),000010.00,1,000120,001112);
----
INSERT INTO DD_OrderLine (OrderDate,SUMofPrice, QuantityPurchased,OrderID,ProductID)
VALUES ((to_date('2013/9/24', 'yyyy/mm/dd')),000010.00,1,000120,001111);

INSERT INTO DD_OrderLine (OrderDate,SUMofPrice, QuantityPurchased,OrderID,ProductID)
VALUES ((to_date('2013/9/24', 'yyyy/mm/dd')),000010.00,1,000120,001116);

INSERT INTO DD_OrderLine (OrderDate,SUMofPrice, QuantityPurchased,OrderID,ProductID)
VALUES ((to_date('2013/9/24', 'yyyy/mm/dd')),000010.00,1,000120,001117);

INSERT INTO DD_OrderLine (OrderDate,SUMofPrice, QuantityPurchased,OrderID,ProductID)
VALUES ((to_date('2013/9/30', 'yyyy/mm/dd')),000010.00,1,000121,001112);

INSERT INTO DD_OrderLine (OrderDate,SUMofPrice, QuantityPurchased,OrderID,ProductID)
VALUES ((to_date('2013/9/30', 'yyyy/mm/dd')),000010.00,1,000122,001112);
```

Are there any ways to count ProductID and make top 10?

Thank you so much

Comment: What does that mean: "could not get top 10"? Did you get top 20 instead? You only have 7 distinct productID values, so at best you will get top 7 I think. However, I don't see where in your query you attempt to determine top anything. I would expect to see `group by` and `order by` in it.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT ProductID
FROM (select ProductID, SUM(QuantityPurchased) AS cnt
      from DD_OrderLine
      WHERE SYSDATE - OrderDate <= 183
      GROUP BY ProductID 
      ORDER BY cnt DESC)
Where ROWNUM <= 10;
```

Comment: Nice. I would do "SYSDATE > ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6)", as an aside.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot specify the ORDER BY clause in an Oracle view ([Here more details](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8004.htm), search ORDER BY and you will find it)

Anyway, in case you need a query where you store the top ten results, even if not ordered, you can use:

```
CREATE VIEW Top10product6month_VW 
AS
SELECT ProductID
  FROM (select ProductID,
               SYSDATE - OrderDate AS OrderAge
          from DD_OrderLine
         WHERE SYSDATE - OrderDate <= 183
      order by QuantityPurchased desc)
 Where ROWNUM <= 10;
```